# How to select element by class in prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have this code below. I need to use a class id instead of the index to update the item.  Say my class name was "initials" How would I use that to update the field instead of an index, just in case someone changed it?

```
 $$('select.employee_select').each( function(elm) {
            elm.observe('change', function(ev) {
                item = elm.childElements().find(function(ele){return !!ele.selected});
                item = item.readAttribute('value');
                elm.up().previousSiblings()[3].update(item); *** I want to change this line by class name instead of the index ***
                serv_id = elm.up().previousSiblings()[13];
                serv_id = serv_id.readAttribute('value');
                employee_id = elm.up().previousSiblings()[4];
                employee_id = employee_id.readAttribute('value');
```

Comment: Is it in the `select.employee_select` array?

Comment: Yes it is, it is looping through elements in a table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to it in array notation:

```
$$('select.employee_select .initials')[0]
```

or if it is the only element with that class:

```
$$('.initials')[0]
```

Comment: Are you saying that instead of: elm.up().previousSiblings()[3].update(item);  I can just use:   $$('select.employee_select .initials')[0]  I am struggling with the details.  So if you have an applicable example that would be very helpful.